# Error mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in al Insertar datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy realizando un sistema en el cual a la hora de ingresar los datos me marca este error.

> Error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
>   in

```
<?php
require("connect_db.php");
if (isset($_POST['descripcion']) && !empty($_POST['descripcion'])) {
    $descripcionTurno = $_POST['descripcion'];
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO ctg_turno (descripcion) values ('$descripcionTurno'");
    echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar Le hace falta pasar la conexión como primer parámetro a [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) *(estilo procedimiento)*,

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT....") { ...}
```

Pero el problema aún mayor es la concatenación de variables en una sentencia, así está propensa a recibir ataques de [Inyección `SQL`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php). Debería emplear sentencias preparadas. *(Ejm base)*

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "midatabase");

if (isset($_POST['descripcion']) && !empty($_POST['descripcion'])) {
    $descripcionTurno = $_POST['descripcion'];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_turno (descripcion) values (?)")) {
        $descripcionTurno = $_POST['descripcion'];
        /* añadir los valores para los marcadores con la variable descripcionTurno*/
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $descripcionTurno);
        /* ejecutamos la consulta */
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "INSERT CORRECTO";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

La función requiere dos argumentos, el primero es la conexión y el segundo el SQL.

Tienes que ponerle la conexión a la función como  argumento a **mysqli_query**, por ejemplo:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
```

**$con** --> Es el primer parámetro, la conexión que has establecido.

**"SELECT * FROM Persons"** --> Es el SQL que quieres ejecutar

Answer (score 2):

El error se debe a que está usando el estilo procedimental de la función [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) como se describe en el manual. El primer parametro debe ser

> Un identificador de enlace devuelto por mysqli_connect() o mysqli_init()

Se aplica al estilo por procediminetos.

Recomiendo que revises también tu estilo de trabajo, no es aconsejable pasar directamente los datos de usuario a la consultas directamente, para eso están las consultas parametrizadas.