# Evitar registros duplicados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un formulario en donde inserto los datos en una base de datos MYSQL, el insert funciona bien pero necesito que si el nombre ya existe no lo deje registrarlo, pero el problema que tengo es que la consulta para ver si existe el nombre no la esta haciendo.

Este es mi archivo PHP donde hago la consulta y el insert

```
<?php
include('cnx.php');

 if($_POST){
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$colonia = $_POST["colonia"];


$busqueda = mysqli_query("SELECT nombre FROM cuponera WHERE nombre ='$nombre'");



if(mysqli_num_rows($busqueda)>0){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Ya existe el nombre")';
    echo '</script>';
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cuponera(nombre,celular,colonia)VALUES('$nombre','$celular','$colonia')";
    if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)){
        echo "Problemas al registrar";
    }else{
        echo "Informacion Registrada";
      
    }

}


   
  };


?>
```

Al momento de imprimir el var_dump() esto me marca

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
   ["current_field"]=>
     int(0)
    ["field_count"]=>
     int(1)
     ["lengths"]=>
     NULL
     ["num_rows"]=>
      int(1)
     ["type"]=>
       int(0)
}
 Nombre ya existe
```

Ya vi que la consulta si esta funcionando porque en la base de datos ya no inserta el dato si es que existe el nombre, pero lo que ahora me esta en duda es que si el nombre existe se manda directo el insert ósea sigue pasando, pero en la base de datos ya no aparece

Todo esto lo paso por medio de AJAX con JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function mensaje(){

    form = document.querySelector('form');

    $('#form-contact').on('submit',function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url:'config/registro2.php',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    if(!data.success == true){
                        console.log(data);
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title:'Información registrada correctamente',
                        });
                    }else{
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title:'Ya existe el nombre',
                        });
                    };
                    
                },
                error:function(xhr,err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
           });
       
        
          e.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(() => {
            form.reset();
        }, 2000);
    
    });
}




mensaje();

 });
```

Ya vi varios tutoriales pero no se cual sea el error que no me hace la consulta.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: haz un `var_dump()` a la variable `$busqueda` y agrega a tu pregunta que resultado obtienes

Comment: mysqli_query() requiere 2 argumentos 1 la  conexion y 2 la query! no obstante utilizas tant modo procedural como orientado a objetos debes decidirte por el que utiliza tu conexion!

Comment: Lo que dijo Byro por 2

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error mysqli\_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in al Insertar datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135594/error-mysqli-query-expects-at-least-2-parameters-1-given-in-al-insertar-datos)

Comment: Está utilizando la sintaxis de objetos.

Comment: Ah, es verdad, en la `$busqueda` usa la procedural, y después objetos, de entrada, debería usar un solo estilo

Comment: Ya cambie la sintaxis y tambien agregue  el argumento en el mysqli_query(), pero sigue sin hacer la consulta, el insert si funciona la consulta es la que no

Comment: Si sigue sin funcionar entonces como te dije comentarios arriba agrega a tu pregunta que obtienes si haces `var_dump($busqueda);`

Comment: @BetaM ok lo hare, lo que note es que cuando hago un insert a la BD un nombre y vuelvo a insertar ese mismo nombre, ya no se registra en la BD

Comment: @BetaM ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: A la primera consulta le falta el parámetro de conexión.

Comment: Ya revise y ya funciona si mando el action directo al PHP, si lo mando por AJAX el problema que tengo es que dice que se mando la informacion pero no la registra, en teoria esta bien pero no debe mandar el mensaje de registro, si no el de error

Answer (score 4):

La verdad es que lo más fácil que puedes hacer (y lo más correcto en mi opinión), es dejarle a la base de datos ese problema.

Tu estructura debería quedar algo así como

```
CREATE TABLE cuponera (
    ...
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ...
)
```

Y ya está... si intentas insertar un nombre que ya existe en la tabla, la propia base de datos lo va a prohibir y te va a regresar un error que puedes cachar con `$mysqli->error`

Answer (score 1):

A esa funcion deberias mandarle como primer parametro tu conexion a la base de datos, y el segundo parametro seria la consulta. Podrias intentar de la siguiente manera:

```
$link = connect(); //Funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$sql = "SELECT nombre FROM cuponera WHERE nombre = "'.$nombre.'; //Consulta sql
$response = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

De esa manera ademas de realizar tu consulta podes manejar de mejor forma el error en caso de que falle. Te recomiendo revisar el [manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) para verlo por tu cuenta de todas formas. Tambien te recominedo que si tu campo va a ser unico, tambien lo asegures desde la base de datos de esta manera:`nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE`
Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar colocando campos `UNIQUE` en la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example(
     name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Y dentro del código PHP usas try carch, yo lo tengo orientado a objetos

```
<?php
class conexion{
    static $host = "127.0.0.1";
    static $user = "root";
    static $password = "";
    static $db = "futbol";

    protected function conn(){
        return new mysqli(self::$host, self::$user, self::$password, self::$db);
    }

    function queryDirect($query){
        $mysqli = self::conn();

        if($mysqli->connect_errno){
            echo "Fallo en la conexión con MYSQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ")" . $mysqli->connect_error;
            exit();
        }

        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        try{
            $mysqli->query($query);
            $output = [
                'error' => False,
                'query' => $query,
            ];
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $output = [
                'error' => True,
                'query' => $query,
            ];
        }

        $mysqli->close();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).